# Regular expression for word that not starts with dot

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

I need to create regular expression for the word not starting with dot and it may contains any alphabet,space and dot.

Ex: sample,sample.test,sample test

regular expression should not allow .sample,sample.,sample .test

how to generate regular expression for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex: `^[^.][\p{L} .]+$` should match what you are after.

The `^` is an anchor which will instruct the regex engine to start matching from the very beginning of the string. `[^.]` will match any 1 character which is not a period (`.`). `[\p{L} .]+` will match one ore more characters which is either a letter (in any language as shown [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)), a white space or a period. Finally, the `$` will instruct the regex to terminate matching at the end of the string.

EDIT: As per your comment question, something like so should be testable: `^[^.][a-zA-Z .]+$`.

Comment: no i tested in http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html not working

Comment: can u post valid regx that i can test with regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html this link?

Comment: @Vetrivelmp: I would recommend you test it out using .NET which is the topic your question belongs to. If I recall correctly not all online regex tools support Unicode.

Comment: thanks it works as i expected. actually as per my posting i modified your regx as ^[^.][a-zA-Z .]+[^.]$

Answer (score 0):

**Use this**

```
\b\p{L}[\p{L}\s.]*\b
```

**Explanation**

```
@"
\b            # Assert position at a word boundary
\p{L}         # A character with the Unicode property “letter” (any kind of letter from any language)
[\p{L}\s.]    # Match a single character present in the list below
                 # A character with the Unicode property “letter” (any kind of letter from any language)
                 # A whitespace character (spaces, tabs, and line breaks)
                 # The character “.”
   *             # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\b            # Assert position at a word boundary
"
```

Comment: here where is the word not starts with dot?

Comment: @Vetrivelmp: The `\b` tags denote the starting and ending of a word. The regex explained above explicitely states that the initial character must be a letter in any case, any language,